# What is meant by mask and effective in the output from getfacl?

Tags: permissions

What is meant by mask and effective in the output from getfacl?

`getfacl /var/www`:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names

file: var/www
owner: Name
group: Name
user::-wx

user:Test:rwx           
effective:r--
group::rw-          
effective:r--

mask::r--

other::rwx
```

Answer (score 26):

ACL are an extended set of permissions.

The POSIX permissions are that each file or directory has an owner, group, and other with read, write, and executable bits.

ACL add additional access, or "mask" and can be used to define additional groups/users and extended permissions.

So what you are seeing is the POSIX permissions + the ACL "mask" and when you put them together you get the effective access.

For example, if you have `rwx` POSIX permissions and ACL gives you `r--` , your effective permissions are read only.

If posix gives you `r--` and ACL gives you `rwx` , your effective permissions are STILL RO.

So you are seeing the POSIX permissions, the ACL mask, and the result or effective permissions. You can then modify either the POSIX or ACL access as needed to give you the effective acces you desire ;)

> Table: Masking of Permissions
>
> Entry type     Text form       Permissions
>
> Named user     user:joe:r-x        r-x
>
> Mask   mask::rw-       rw-
>
> Effective permissions  r-

See

[http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/POSIX_ACL_on_Linux.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20121022035645/http://vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/POSIX_ACL_on_Linux.html)

Especially the "Table: Masking of Permissions", which I tried to quote above, and the first section "How ACLs Work"

Comment: I got the difference between POSIX and ACL: ACL means extended permissions for more users and groups. But what the difference between mask and effective permissions? BTW the linked website does not exist.

Comment: Effective permissions = posit permissions + ACL mask

Answer (score 1):

It took me a little while to figure this out, so maybe this will be helpful.

Consider the output from `ls -l`. If you're familiar enough with POSIX, you'll be used to interpreting something like this:

`drwxr-x--x 2 root plebs ...`

- The first letter is the type: `d` means it's a directory.
- The next three are the owner's permissions: `rwx` means the owner can read, write and execute (search).
- The "middle three" are the owning group's permissions: `r-x` means the group can read and execute (search) only.
- The last three are the "other" or "world" permissions: `--x` means others can only execute (search).
- There's a link count which isn't relevant to this discussion.
- The owner (`root`) is named.
- The owning group (`plebs`) is named.

When there's an ACL in effect, the "middle three" change: instead of being the owning group's permissions, they are the *maximum permission that will be granted to a non-owner mentioned in the ACL*.

For example, say I do this to the directory above:

`setfacl --modify user:hero:7 thedir`

That grants access `rwx` to `hero`, and now the `ls -l` output will look like:

`drwxrwx--x+ 2 root plebs ...`

The `+` indicates there's an ACL now.

I didn't change the permissions for the `plebs` group, and `getfacl thedir` will confirm it, showing something like this:

```
user::rwx
user:hero:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::--x
```

The owning group still only has `r-x` permissions, but the thing showing in the "middle three" is actually the mask.

I can use ordinary `chmod` to change it.

`chmod 651 thedir`

And it looks like it worked in `ls -l`:

`drwxr-x--x+ 2 root plebs ...`

And `getfacl thedir`:

```
user::rwx
user:hero:rwx    #effective:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::--x
```

Ah, look, because I changed the mask, which is the maximum permission that will be granted to a non-owner mentioned in the ACL, `hero` can't be given `rwx` permissions any more. Even though they have an `rwx` entry in the ACL, because the mask has been restricted, they can only get `r-x` (only `r-x` is effective).

The mask will only ever restrict permissions, it won't add them. Even when the mask was `rwx` before, the owning group still only got `r-x` permissions, in accordance with the ACL entry.

This behaviour is handy because the "middle three" give you an upper bound on the permissions granted in an ACL, and since ACLs are often used as ad-hoc groups, when they are in effect, they're often of more interest than the owning group.